# Why is slice an impure pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe

I've always believed that `slice` is pure and it's sole advantage over calling `slice` method on string or array is caching mechanism of pure pipes in Angular.

Turns out it isn't the case and `slice` is impure. Moreover implementation is very basic: it guards against `null`s and delegates to `slice` method. No internal comparison of last transformed input.

I suspect it is designed to align with behavior of `ngFor`, but is it a viable reason? Newcomers would complain that *Angular is broken* otherwise I suppose, but then again why should I use this pipe?

Am I correct that it creates new arrays in every change detection run, which leads to triggering even `OnPush` change detection down the three and nullifying performance optimizations?

Edit: This question is based on assumption that one should use immutable data.

Comment: Never had to use it, im slicing arrays on component backend .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This pipe is impure because it would otherwise return the same result until the array reference changes, so it wouldn't work when the array items change.

I personally think it is bad design to use such pipes. They removed the [FilterPipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe) because of performance issues. Indeed, a pipe is triggered on every change detection, and there are many! I think the slice pipe should be removed as well. For me it's a quick and dirty solution, that brings more problems than it solves.

I suggest you slice your arrays yourself when needed.

Comment: I think it there should be injection token that conditionally configures pure variant of pipes like `slice` & newest `keyvalue` for advanced users.

Comment: @TomaszBłachut yes that could be good, then we could push changes by reassigning an array, like the `OnPush` change detection behavior for components

Comment: You can do it by yourself while it's not built-in!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Guerric P [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274049/4858777), sometimes it might be convenient to have a pure slice pipe. Fortunately it's easy to create one:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'pureSlice'
})
export class PureSlicePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(str: string, start?: number, end?: number): string;
    transform<T>(arr: readonly T[], start?: number, end?: number): T[];
    transform(obj: string | readonly unknown[], start?: number, end?: number): string | unknown[] {
        return obj.slice(start, end);
    }
}
```